# Span vertical align top inside table

Tags: css

I have a span which is inside a table and inside Div. I want this span to appear at top of page

Below is the code

```
 <table width="100%">
    <tr valign="middle">
        <td width="50%" align="center" height="700">
            <div id="divAlert" runat="server" style="font-size: 26px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
              <span>Please try back after some time</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know that if i give Vertical-align property to TD the span will appear at the top of page.
But is there any way i can specify some property to span which will move the text inside span to top of page.

I want to achieve this only by adding some property to span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I could think is what you already know, that is by adding style `vertical-align: top;` to the `td` element

But if you want the other way, you can also use this without `position: absolute;`

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr valign="middle">
    <td width="50%" align="center" height="700">
      <div id="divAlert" runat="server" style="font-size: 26px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
        <span style="height:700px;display:inline-block">Please try back after some time</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you just need to specify the `height` of the `span`, the same with the `td` element that contain it, set the `width:100%` so there won't be another `inline` element beside it, and set `display:inline-block` so the `width` and `height` can work.

Note: This should only be used if there's only 1 `element` inside the `td`, which is the `span`

Answer (score 2):

Without using absolute positioning, you can simply do this

```
table tr td{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ft9kfp5p/).

Comment: He already know about that, what He ask is `But is there any way i can specify some property to span which will move the text inside span to top of page` please recheck his question.

Comment: I don't think you can move the TEXT without moving the span itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish that. because that margin is provided by the td tag

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" height="100%" align="center" height="700">
            <div id="divAlert" runat="server" style="font-size: 26px;">
              <span>Please try back after some time</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```